# Delay between animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, time, delay

I amm working on rotation of objects around a circle. I want to stop the animation when a box reachs at top, there should be a delay of seconds then start animation until next box reaches on top.

Code Snippet:

```
if(x==40.109375 && y==218.015625){
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(animate, 1000);
}
```

`x` and `y` are the coordinates of top position

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p876D/)

[image: Should stop when reach at red circled position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a timeout before the animation starts again. Do it this way :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    timer = setInterval(animate, 35);
 },1000);
```

As you mentioned it, weird things happen if the mouse enters/leaves the box many times. To work around it, one solution would be to check the state of `timer` before changing it. Please see this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/p876D/3/

Or, as you have done it, clearing the timeout would work too

http://jsfiddle.net/p876D/4/

Comment: just focus in the box, let it be stopped once, then loose the focus and again hover, it increases the speed

Comment: Indeed ! I will try to find a fix !

Answer (score 0):

A timeout would delay the start of the next interval

```
if(x==40.109375 && y==218.015625){
    clearInterval(timer);
    setTimeout(function() {
        timer = setInterval(animate, 100);
    }, 1000);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p876D/1/)